# With socket.io and node, is it possible to emit to browser from server in response to an event not triggered by the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

New to socket.io and node.js.  I have a working hello world for socket.io, so I understand the basics and have it emitting to browser.

An totally separate, external server is going to POST to my node.js server when an environmental sensor sends some data.  I want my node app to receive that event, parse out its text, and then forward/emit that text to my browser.  So what's distinct about this is the browser is connected but it's not initiating the event that is going to fire the emit.

I can't figure out how to structure the code or whether this is possible.  I'm assuming node and socket.io are flexible enough that they can do this.

I could post the demo code but it's just a hello world, what I think I simply need is advice on what to put in the route for capturing the incoming http POST.  Would this be a call to a global function that then calls emit()?  Or is there some way for my **server** code to fire an event that io.sockets.on() can capture?

Thanks

Comment: "_I am using an external service that is going to POST to my node.js app_" , does that service sends that request from browser ?

Comment: No, the external service is a server that sends a POST to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is certainly possible. When the external server's event is fired submit a post request to your node application server. First your node app needs to create an http server in order to receive the incoming post request.

**Server**

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.method == 'POST') {
        var postData = '';

        req.on('data', function(data) {
            postData += data;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            console.log("Post request received: " + postData);
        })
    }
});

var port = 3000;
var host = 'localhost';
server.listen(port, host);
console.log("Server started on http://" + host + ":" + port)
```

Then your external server can make a post request to your node app server. On the req.on('end') you can then forward the data to your webbrowser using socket.io

Comment: Thanks Plee but this doesn't address the core problem of showing how to implement two socket.io connections.  Appreciate the input though.  It's a difficult scenario to discuss because of the number of connections.

Comment: I thought you understood how to implement the socket.io connections and emitting to the browser? If you do then just call socket.emit() your data to your web browser from the req.on

If you are having issues with socket.io what exactly are you having issues with? Multiple connections or just basic emission?

Answer (score 0):

I had to resolve this by creating two node.js apps, one to receive incoming messages over http, and the other to serve the browser.  the two apps communicate with one another over http.  The core problem i had was figuring out how to establish two simultaneous socket.io connections in one node app.  There's probably a way, but I could find on one doing that.